grafana-helm-charts version 7.0.0 unable to pull public image from ecr
Pulling image "docker.io/public.ecr.aws/nslhub/grafana:10.4.0"
Warning  Failed     7s (x2 over 22s)   kubelet            Failed to pull image "docker.io/public.ecr.aws/nslhub/grafana:10.4.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/public.ecr.aws/nslhub/grafana:10.4.0": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/public.ecr.aws/nslhub/grafana:10.4.0": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
This is the error in the pod having issue with grafana-helm-charts , trying to upgrade from 6.56.1 to 7.0.0 or above
my grafana-image and helm version
the version in the image and helm version are running fine in the cluster
reverted the helm-charts version for now , but having this issue in higher grafana-helm-charts versions , tested for 7.0.0 and 6.61.2 , both are not working any suggestions

Configure registry, respository, tag, ... correctly. E. g.:
image:
  registry: public.ecr.aws
  repository: nslhub/grafana
  tag: "10.4.0"
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

